# In Oracle PL/SQL, how do i iterate/access a collection containing the result of LISTAGG function

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Assuming table EMP has three columns (deptno, ename and salary).
How would i write a for loop that would look like this and be able to access the items in the LISTAGG function

```
BEGIN

    FOR rec IN (SELECT deptno, LISTAGG(ename, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ename) AS employees
                 FROM   emp
                 WHERE deptNo = 'XYZ'
                 GROUP BY deptno)
    LOOP

        Update EMP
        set salary = 10000
        WHERE ename in (THE ITEMS IN THE LISTAGG)

        FOR EACH (ITEM RETURNED IN THE LISTAGG)
           DO SOMETHING
        END;

    END LOOP;
END;
```

Basically i want to know two things,

- How can i refer to all the items in returned by the listagg function (See UPDATE statement inside for loop)
- How can i iterate through each of the items returned by teh listagg function. See INNER FOR LOOP.
- Would the syntax for the above also work for WM_CONCAT and COLLECT functions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `listagg()`  does not return a collection. It returns a single string value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using PL/SQL ListAGG Function Results in a Procedural Loop

Here is a sample application of the OP's request:

```
BEGIN

FOR rec IN (SELECT deptno, LISTAGG(ename, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ename) AS employees
             FROM  emp
             WHERE deptNo = 'XYZ'
             GROUP BY deptno)
 LOOP

    Update EMP
    set salary = 10000
    WHERE ename in

    ( select regexp_substr(rec.employees,'[^,]+',1,level)
        from dual
     connect by level <= length(regexp_replace(rec.employees,'[^,]+')) + 1
        )

    AND deptNo=rec.deptNo; --not to miss this filter condition

    FOR EACH (ITEM RETURNED IN THE LISTAGG)
       DO SOMETHING
    END;

 END LOOP;
END;
```

To see another working example of parsing a delimited string list, see Stack Overflow for a similar problem involving a [delimited string parsing routine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14829972/split-string-using-pl-sql-using-connect-level-on-null-value).