# Split Column value to pick last two strings

Tags: sql, regex, string, oracle

In oracle, I need to find the last two values in a pipe separated column . The data looks like below

```
MyCol 
--------
a|b|c|d
e|f
g
h|i|j
k|l|m|n|o
```

My output should be as below

```
MyCol     ColA         ColB
----------------------------
a|b|c|d   c             d
e|f       e             f
g         null          g
h|i|j     i             j
k|l|m|n|o n             o
```

For two levels, I am able to write a select query using the REGEX split like below

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(MyCol, '[^|]+', 1,1),REGEXP_SUBSTR(MyCol, '[^|]+', 1,2)
```

How can i achieve this for multiple levels.

Comment: What do you mean, "multiple levels?"

Comment: i meant the number of pipe delimited values. a|b is 2 levels, a|b|c is 3 levels and so on

Comment: Shouldn't the "g" line be NULL, then 'g'?

Comment: @Gary_W , yes, it should be null then g. edited accordingly

Comment: I updated my example to reflect the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way that works with NULL elements.  Its a tad brute force:

```
SQL> with tbl(str) as (
    select 'a|b|c|d' from dual
    union
    select 'e|f' from dual
    union
    select 'g' from dual
    union
    select 'h|i|j' from dual
    union
    select 'k|l|m|n|o' from dual
    --regexp_substr() args: string, pattern, position, occurance, match_param, subexpr
    )
      SELECT str,
             REGEXP_SUBSTR( str ,
                            '([^\|]*)(\||$)',
                            1,
                            CASE REGEXP_COUNT( str ,'\|')
                              WHEN 0 THEN NULL  -- 1 element only
                              ELSE REGEXP_COUNT( str ,'\|')
                            END,
                            NULL,
                            1 ) AS ColA,
             REGEXP_SUBSTR( str ,
                            '([^\|]*)(\||$)',
                            1,
                            CASE (REGEXP_COUNT( str ,'\|')+1)
                              WHEN 1 THEN 1-- 1 element only
                              ELSE (REGEXP_COUNT( str ,'\|')+1)
                            END,
                            NULL,
                            1 ) AS ColB
      FROM   tbl;

STR       COLA      COLB
--------- --------- ---------
a|b|c|d   c         d
e|f       e         f
g                   g
h|i|j     i         j
k|l|m|n|o n         o

SQL>
```

Caveat: There needs to be at least one value in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to come up with something. Enter r=1 for the first value and r=2 for the second.

```
select v
  from (select v
              ,l
              ,rownum r
          from (select v
                      ,l
                  from (select regexp_substr('A|B|C|D', '[^|]+', 1, level) v
                              ,level l
                          from dual
                        connect by regexp_substr('A|B|C|D', '[^|]+', 1, level) is not null)
                 order by l desc)
         where rownum < 3)
 where r = 1
```

From the inside out. This query will list the individual values:

```
select regexp_substr('A|B|C|D', '[^|]+', 1, level) v
      ,level l
  from dual
connect by regexp_substr('A|B|C|D', '[^|]+', 1, level) is not null

A 1
B 2
C 3
D 4
```

The query around that reverses the order so we get:

```
D 4
C 3
B 2
A 1
```

Then we limit the result to the first two rows (rownum<3) and assign new rownumbers (rownum r)

```
D 1
C 2
```

So in the end we are able to select r=1 or r=2.

Thanks to this blog:
https://blogs.oracle.com/aramamoo/entry/how_to_split_comma_separated_string_and_pass_to_in_clause_of_select_statement

Comment: Parsing regex of the format '[^|]+' fails when there are null list elements.  Be careful using it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464275/split-comma-seperated-values-to-columns/31464699#31464699

Comment: Thanks Gary, learned about regexp_count from your solution today.