# Convert "regexp_substr" (Oracle ) to PostgreSQL

Tags: oracle, postgresql, rownum, regexp-substr

I have the query In Oracle SQL:

```
       select town_name, 
              regexp_substr(town_name, '[^A,]+', 1, 1) as c1,
              regexp_substr(town_name, '[^A,]+', 1, 2) as c2, 
              regexp_substr(town_name, '[^A,]+', 1, rownum) as c_rownum,
              rownum
          from epr_towns
```

The first 2 rows from the result are:

```
VALGANNA        V   LG  V   1
VARANO BORGHI   V   R   R   2
```

I need to obtain the same result on PostgreSQL (for the row with `regexp_substr(town_name, '[^A,]+', 1, rownum) as c_rownum`), and I don't know how. 
Could you help me?
Thanks.

Comment: The input is "town_name" ("VALGANNA" for the first row).

Comment: The actual values are VALGANNA  and VARANO BORGHI (column 1). The columns 2..4 are the results obtained with "regexp_substr" in Oracle.

Comment: Warning!  The regex of the format '[^A,]+' commonly used for parsing delimited strings fails when there are NULL elements in the list.  Make sure you test thoroughly.  Always expect the unexpected!  See here for more details and an improved regex.  I don't know how it would translate to Postgres though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464275/split-comma-separated-values-to-columns-in-oracle/31464699#31464699

Answer (score 7):

There's really two separate problems here

- replacing rownum
- replacing regexp_substr with regexp_matches

To solve for rownum, use a CTE (`WITH` clause) to add a rownum-like column to your underlying table.

`regexp_matches` works a little differently than Oracle `regexp_substr`.  While Oracle `regexp_substr` takes the nth match as an argument, PostgreSQL `regexp_matches` will return *all* matches as a table-valued function.  So you have to wrap the call in a subquery with limit/offset to pluck out the nth match.  Also, the rows returned by `regexp_substr` are arrays, so assuming you have no parenthesized expressions in your regexp, you need to index/dereference the first item in the array.

End result looks like this:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/865ee/7

```
 with epr_towns_rn as (
    select town_name,
      row_number() over(order by town_name) as rn
  from epr_towns
)
select town_name,
   (select (regexp_matches(town_name, '[^A,]+', 'g'))[1] offset 0 limit 1) as c1,
   (select (regexp_matches(town_name, '[^A,]+', 'g'))[1] offset 1 limit 1) as c2,
   (select (regexp_matches(town_name, '[^A,]+', 'g'))[1] offset rn-1 limit 1)
     as c_rownum,
   rn
   from epr_towns_rn;
```

If you only wanted the first match, you could leave out the 'g' argument and leave out the limit/offset from the subquery but you still need the subquery wrapper in case there's no match, to mimic regexp_substr returning null when no match.

Answer (score 3):

You can find your case and other scenarios on this page:
https://pgxn.org/dist/orafce/doc/sql_migration/sql_migration03.html

--

In short you can do something like that:
from OracleDB:

```sql
SELECT
    REGEXP_SUBSTR('one two three four five ',
    '(\S*)\s') AS "REGEXP"
FROM DUAL;
```

Result: one

to PostgreSQL:

```sql
SELECT (
    SELECT array_to_string(a, '') AS "REGEXP"
    FROM regexp_matches('one two three four five ',
    '(\S*)\s',
    'g') AS f(a)
    LIMIT 1
);
```

Result: one

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a table, so I use generate for example:

```
   select town_name, 
          regexp_substr(town_name, '[^A,]+', 1, 1) as c1,
          regexp_substr(town_name, '[^A,]+', 1, 2) as c2, 
          regexp_substr(town_name, '[^A,]+', 1, dense_rank() over (order by town_name)) as c_rownum,
          dense_rank() over (order by c)
      from epr_towns
```

I believe you look for dense_rank window function?..

NB. it is always easier to have SQL fiddle or initial code

Comment: I am have been looking for dense_rank() and conversion of regexp_substr() with 4 parameters (for 2 parameters, it works "substring(town_name, '[^A,]+')" )