# How to get first two characters from the first two words of a given string in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to get first two characters from first two words given in Oracle. Example follows:

**example:**

```
 string--> 'ganjikunta ramesh varma'

 output-->  ga ra
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34208563/plsql-best-way-to-split-string and then https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/substr.php

Comment: it's very easy to do using for loop and substr like any other programming language.. question is that enough for you or do you need to implement it as part of a single sql query ?

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve it using combination of `substr` and `instr`. Try this:

```
Select substr(your_str, 1, 2) 
       || substr(your_str, instr(your_str, ' '), 3) -- 3 is used to fetch space and two charcters
From dual;
```

Cheers!!