# Why this regexp in Oracle SQL loses the beginning of string?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, split, regexp-substr

I'm splitting a string `p_value` using `p_delimeter`, which may contain one or more symbols (that's why regexp is not like often used `[^,]+`).

In most of the cases the following query works predictably, but I'm dazed with a case when:

1. string `p_value` contains line break `chr(10)`,
2. `p_value` **doesn't** contain `p_delimeter` as substring,

so I expect to have one row with the whole `p_value` as the result, but got only the remainder after line break.

It's supposed here that regexp treats line break as ordinary symbol, since
the `'m'` modifier is absent in call to `regexp_substr`.

Please, explain is this behavior correct and how to get the expected result.

---

```
WITH 
  params AS (SELECT 'ab' || chr(10) || 'cd' p_value,
                    'xxx' p_delimeter
               FROM dual
  )          
SELECT regexp_substr(p_value, '(.*?)(' || p_delimeter || '|$)', 1, level, 'c', 1) AS CUT
  FROM params
CONNECT BY regexp_substr(p_value, '(.*?)(' || p_delimeter || '|$)', 1, level, 'c', 1) IS NOT NULL;


Actual result:      Expected result:
-----               ------
 CUT                 CUT
-----               ------ 
 cd                  ab/cd 
                       ^
                       'this is just a marker for a line break [= chr(10)]'
```

Comment: Line breaks are matched with `.` when you pass `n` modifier, use `'cn'`. *If the `n` flag is set, it matches the newline character. The newline is recognized as the linefeed character (`\x0a`) on UNIX and Windows or the carriage return character (`\x0d`) on Macintosh platforms*. See [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm).

Comment: @Wiktor, thank you, it's useful. But if we add `'n'` modifier, then line break cannot be used as `p_delimeter`.

Comment: A line feed can be used as a delimiter since you are using a lazy quantifier `*?` with `.`.

Comment: FYI - You mention the oft-used regex pattern of `[^,]+` to split delimited strings.  It fails if there is a NULL in the list and it should be avoided.  See here for proof and an alternative regex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464275/split-comma-separated-values-to-columns-in-oracle/31464699#31464699

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allow the `.` pattern to match all characters by adding the `n` flag to the regular expression:

```
WITH params ( p_value, p_delimiter ) AS (
  SELECT 'ab' || chr(10) || 'cd', 'xxx' FROM dual
)          
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(p_value, '(.*?)(' || p_delimeter || '|$)', 1, level, 'cn', 1) AS CUT
  FROM params
CONNECT BY LEVEL < REGEXP_COUNT( p_value, '(.*?)(' || p_delimeter || '|$)' );
```

or you can use a simple function:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TYPE VARCHAR2_TABLE AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION split_String(
  i_str    IN  VARCHAR2,
  i_delim  IN  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ','
) RETURN VARCHAR2_TABLE DETERMINISTIC
AS
  p_result       VARCHAR2_TABLE := VARCHAR2_TABLE();
  p_start        NUMBER(5) := 1;
  p_end          NUMBER(5);
  c_len CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_str );
  c_ld  CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_delim );
BEGIN
  IF c_len > 0 THEN
    p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
    WHILE p_end > 0 LOOP
      p_result.EXTEND;
      p_result( p_result.COUNT ) := SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, p_end - p_start );
      p_start := p_end + c_ld;
      p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
    END LOOP;
    IF p_start <= c_len + 1 THEN
      p_result.EXTEND;
      p_result( p_result.COUNT ) := SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, c_len - p_start + 1 );
    END IF;
  END IF;
  RETURN p_result;
END;
/
```

**Query**:

```
WITH params ( p_value, p_delimiter ) AS (
  SELECT 'ab' || chr(10) || 'cd', 'xxx' FROM dual
)          
SELECT COLUMN_VALUE AS CUT
FROM   params,
       TABLE( split_String( p_value, p_delimiter ) );
```