# PL/SQL, regexp, connect by

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql

2 sample's of code:

```
      WITH A AS
  (SELECT 'this is a test:12/01/2015  01/05/2018'
    || chr(13)
    ||chr(10)
    || ' this is the 2nd line: 07/07/2017' Description
  FROM dual
  )
SELECT to_date(regexp_substr(A.Description , '\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}',1,level),'MM/DD/YYYY')
FROM A
  CONNECT BY level  <= regexp_count(a.description, '\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}');
/
```

and another:

```
SELECT DISTINCT REGEXP_SUBSTR ('23,34,45,56','[^,]+',1,LEVEL) as "token"
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR ('23,34,45,56','[^,]+',1,LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
order by 1;
```

Can someone explain me, why in 1st case we use '<=' and in 2nd we don't?

Comment: In the first example you can also use `IS NOT NULL` ==> just `CONNECT BY  regexp_substr(a.description, '\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}', 1, level) is not null`. And in the second example yu can use `CONNECT BY level <= REGEXP_count ('23,34,45,56','[\,]+') + 1` instead `IS NOT NULL`. It hard to say why some has choosen `is not null` instead of `regexp_count`, it could be simply  a personal preference, In my opinion.

Comment: Avoid using the regex in that second select for parsing delimited lists.  It does not handle NULL list elements and will return incorrect values silently.  See here for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464275/split-comma-separated-values-to-columns-in-oracle/31464699#31464699

Answer (score 0):

```
Introduced in Oracle 10g
```

REGEXP_SUBSTR - Returns the string matching the regular expression.

```
Introduced in Oracle 11g
```

REGEXP_COUNT - Returns the number of occurrences of the regular expression in the string.

The same you can achieve by without using relational operator '<='  .
In your above code you are counting the occurrence .

```
WITH A AS
      (SELECT 'this is a test:12/01/2015  01/05/2018'
        || chr(13)
        ||chr(10)
        || ' this is the 2nd line: 07/07/2017' Description
      FROM dual
      )
    SELECT to_date(regexp_substr(A.Description , '\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}',1,level),'MM/DD/YYYY')
    FROM A
      CONNECT BY   
      regexp_substr(A.Description , '\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}',1,LEVEL) is not null;
```

In your second query you can make use of '<=' as per the need.

```
SELECT DISTINCT REGEXP_SUBSTR ('23,34,45,56','[^,]+',1,LEVEL) as "token",LEVEL
        FROM   DUAL
    CONNECT BY LEVEL  <= regexp_count(('23,34,45,56'),'[^,]+');
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the number of rows found using `IS NOT NULL` on the output of `REGEXP_SUBSTR` is the same as the number of rows from `REGEXP_COUNT` and then they do the same thing and it is a matter of personal preference:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( '1,2,3', '\d+', 1, LEVEL ) AS value
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT( '1,2,3', '\d+' )
```

and

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( '1,2,3', '\d+', 1, LEVEL ) AS value
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR( '1,2,3', '\d+', 1, LEVEL ) IS NOT NULL
```

both output:

```
VALUE
-----
1
2
3
```

However, sometimes the sub-string matched can be zero-width (which is equivalent to `NULL`) and then they do not:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( '1,2,,4', '(\d*)(,|$)', 1, LEVEL, 1 ) AS value
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT( '1,2,3', '(\d*)(,|$)' )
```

Outputs:

```
VALUE
------
1
2
(null)
4
(null)
```

and:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( '1,2,,4', '(\d*)(,|$)', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 1 ) AS value
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR( '1,2,,4', '(\d*)(,|$)', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 1 ) IS NOT NULL
```

Outputs:

```
VALUE
------
1
2
```

and stops at the first `NULL` value.

To get all the results you either need to use `REGEXP_COUNT` or not have the `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` function return `NULL` values in the `CONNECT BY` clause (so, in this example we could fix it by extracting the full match rather than just the capturing group; i.e. `REGEXP_SUBSTR( '1,2,,4', '(\d*)(,|$)', 1, LEVEL ) IS NOT NULL`).