# Oracle db: How to add spaces in specific positions in strings

Tags: sql, string, oracle, regex-lookarounds, regexp-replace

Suppose I have a string (varchar2) and I want to add a space wherever I have two consecutive a's. So for example:  `'graanh' -> 'gra anh'`.

OK, this is trivial to do, either with `replace` or `regexp_replace`. But both choke on **three** or more consecutive a's. For example:

```
SQL> select replace('aaaaa', 'aa', 'a a') from dual;

REPLACE
-------
a aa aa

SQL> select regexp_replace('aaaaa', 'aa', 'a a') from dual;

REGEXP_
-------
a aa aa
```

This is because the search for the "next" occurrence of the match pattern begins after the end of the "previous" one. Indeed, `regexp_count('aaaaa', 'aa')` returns 2, not 4.

The desired result is `'aaaaa' -> 'a a a a a'`.

The problem, really, is that I don't want to replace the pattern `'aa'`. What I do want to replace is the empty string BETWEEN a's on both sides of the empty string. So the description would be something like: Find all occurrences of an empty string with a's on both sides of it, and replace that empty string with a space.

Can this be done with string or regexp functions? Please do **not** offer solutions with recursive queries, or (the horror!) PL/SQL procedures; I know they can be done, but I am interested in whether there is a "natural" solution, a tool that exists precisely for this question, that I am missing.

Worst case, `replace(replace('aaaaa', 'aa', 'a a'), 'aa', 'a a')` will do the trick. Is this the **best** case as well?

Lest you think this is a weird requirement: I am experimenting with different methods of splitting comma-separated strings. Some of the methods have a very nasty habit of ignoring NULL tokens within such strings (that is, from two consecutive commas you don't get a NULL, as you should). So, before using those methods, one would have to parse the input string and add a space, or the string 'NULL', or something, between consecutive commas. Of course, it would be better to add a space after EVERY comma (and at the beginning of the string), and after splitting into tokens, to remove a space from the beginning of each token; but this raised the question I asked above, which I think has merit on its own.

Thank you!

**EDIT** (13 April 2020) I learned a lot about regular expressions since I first posted this question. Now I know the terminology for this. (I find that the explanation I gave is correct, I just wasn't using technical terms for it.) What we need here, to be able to add spaces everywhere they are needed in a single pass, is **lookarounds** - and Oracle regular expressions don't support them. **END EDIT**

Comment: Ha!  When I went to find this post as an FYI to mention a method of parsing a string that allows for nulls, I noticed you edited it.  :-)  http://stackoverflow.com/a/31464699/2543416

Comment: What about building your own built-in? with java not PL/SQL of course?

Comment: @J.Chomel - I could do that (after I learn Java); question is, would it be any more efficient than that double call to `replace`? Somehow I suspect the context switching will be more expensive than calling `replace` twice. Moreover, my main purpose with this question was to learn if there were some string functions or features or techniques that I was missing. It's several months later, I've learned more, and I believe the answer to that more general question is NO.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you truly find PL/SQL *the horror* and recursive queries unnatural, then you probably have to go with `replace(replace('aaaaa', 'aa', 'a a'), 'aa', 'a a')`, as you already have proposed, albeit as "worst case". Why you consider this the *worst* case remains unclear to me.

Comment: To be clear: I use recursive queries all the time, and there is at least one case I know of (implementing Eratosthenes' algorithm) where PL/SQL works a lot better than anything plain-SQL. I meant FOR THIS PROBLEM a recursive CTE would be unnatural, and PL/SQL unnecessary (since there's no way it would allow a simpler/better solution than the "worst case" I already mentioned). I just didn't want to see solutions with FOR loops for this. If you can suggest a recursive CTE or PL/SQL solution simpler than replace(replace()), by all means please suggest it.

Comment: I consider it the "worst case" in the sense that any offered solution should be no worse than it (than the "worst case"). The "best case" would be a regexp (or similar) solution that searches for a pattern and allows replacing a sub-pattern within that pattern, as I explained in my post. Sorry if that wasn't clear, I did my best to explain it but perhaps failed.