# Regexp_substr is not working as expected

Tags: sql, oracle11g

So, I have a piece of simple SQL like:

```
select 
REGEXP_SUBSTR (randomcol, '[^|]+', 1, 2)
||'|'||       REGEXP_SUBSTR (randomcol, '[^|]+', 1, 3)
||'|'||       REGEXP_SUBSTR (randomcol, '[^|]+', 1, 4)
from table1 where ADDTL_DETAIL_INFO is not null and module_key='01-07-2016 00:00:00/2212/    1';
```

The idea is to get the pipe separated values present in the randomcol column where the value present is:

```
~custom|HELLO1||HELLO3
```

So I need the values like HELLO1,whitespace (as there is no value between the second pipe and the third pipe) and HELLO3.

But when I ran the above query it returns as:

```
HELLO1|HELLO3|
```

and the white space is gone. I need this white space to retain. So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You are not doing anything wrong, Oracle is - by treating an empty string the same as null. Sometime in the distant future, Oracle will go out of business or they will fix this (whichever comes first).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex of the form `'[^|]+'` does not work with NULL list elements and should be avoided!  See this post for more info: [Split comma separated values to columns in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464275/split-comma-separated-values-to-columns-in-oracle/31464699#31464699)

Use this form instead:

```
select regexp_substr('1,2,3,,5,6', '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, 5, NULL, 1) from dual;
```

Which can be read as "get the 1st remembered group of the 5th occurrence of the set of characters ending with a comma or the end of the line".

So for your 4th element, you would use this to preserve the NULL in element 3 (assuming you want to build it by separate elements and not just grab the string from the character after the first separator to the end):

```
...
REGEXP_SUBSTR (addtl_detail_info, '(.*?)(\||$)', 1, 2) ||
REGEXP_SUBSTR (addtl_detail_info, '(.*?)(\||$)', 1, 3) ||
REGEXP_SUBSTR (addtl_detail_info, '(.*?)(\||$)', 1, 4)
...
```

You know, this may be easier.  Just grab everything after the first pipe:

```
SQL> select REGEXP_replace('~custom|HELLO1||HELLO3', '^.*?\|(.*)', '\1') result
   from dual;

RESULT
--------------
HELLO1||HELLO3

SQL>
```

The parenthesis surround what you want to "remember" and the replace string references the 1st remembered group with "\1".

Comment: Thank you very much. I was unaware of this usage. Thanks also for the link provided.

Comment: You bet, I've been on a one-man mission to make folks aware of the `'[^|]+'` problem!  Here's a perfect example.

Comment: @Mistu4u  Please see the edit for a possible easier solution.