# Parse Values with Delimiters Using REGEXP_SUPSTR in Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, regexp-substr

I have a table called TVL_DETAIL that contains column TVL_CD_LIST.  Column TVL_CD_LIST contains three records:
**TVL_CD_LIST:**
M1180_Z6827
K5900_Z6828
I2510

I've used the following code in an attempt to return the values only(so excluding the underscore):

```
SELECT
TVL_CD_LIST   
FROM TVL_DETAIL  
WHERE TVL_CD_LIST IN (SELECT regexp_substr(TVL_CD_LIST,'[^_]+', 1, level) FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY regexp_substr(TVL_CD_LIST,'[^_]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL)
```

What I was expecting to see returned in separate rows was:
M1180
Z6827
K5900
Z6828
I2510

But it only returns I2510(which is the original value that doesn't contain an underscore).

What am I doing wrong?  Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you are querying for the list where it matches a sub-element and that will only happen where the list is comprised of one element.  What you really wanted to select are the sub-elements themselves.

Note: Explanation of why parsing strings using the regex form `'[^_]+'` is bad here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31464699/2543416

You want to parse the list, selecting the elements:

```
SQL> with TVL_DETAIL(TVL_CD_LIST) as (
     select 'M1180_Z6827' from dual union
     select 'K5900_Z6828' from dual union
     select 'I2510' from dual
   )
   SELECT distinct regexp_substr(TVL_CD_LIST, '(.*?)(_|$)', 1, level, NULL, 1) element
   FROM TVL_DETAIL
   CONNECT BY level <= LENGTH(regexp_replace(TVL_CD_LIST, '[^_]', '')) + 1;
   -- 11g  CONNECT BY level <= regexp_count(TVL_CD_LIST, '_') + 1;

ELEMENT
-----------
Z6827
K5900
M1180
I2510
Z6828

SQL>
```

And this is cool if you want to track by row and element within row:

```
SQL> with TVL_DETAIL(row_nbr, TVL_CD_LIST) as (
     select 1, 'M1180_Z6827' from dual union
     select 2, 'K5900_Z6828' from dual union
     select 3, 'I2510' from dual
   )
   SELECT row_nbr, column_value substring_nbr,
          regexp_substr(TVL_CD_LIST, '(.*?)(_|$)', 1, column_value, NULL, 1) element
   FROM TVL_DETAIL,
     TABLE(
       CAST(
         MULTISET(SELECT LEVEL
                  FROM dual
                  CONNECT BY level <= LENGTH(regexp_replace(TVL_CD_LIST, '[^_]', '')) + 1
                  -- 11g CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(TVL_CD_LIST, '_')+1
                  ) AS sys.OdciNumberList
           )
     )
   order by row_nbr, substring_nbr;

   ROW_NBR SUBSTRING_NBR ELEMENT
---------- ------------- -----------
         1             1 M1180
         1             2 Z6827
         2             1 K5900
         2             2 Z6828
         3             1 I2510

SQL>
```

EDIT:  Oops, edited to work with 10g as REGEXP_COUNT is not available until 11g.

Comment: Thanks Gary_W...so when I run the query, I get an this error: ORA-00939: too many arguments for function

Comment: Check your syntax carefully, as you can see it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The query you have used creates the list but you are comparing the list of record with column it self using the `in` clause, as such `M1180` or `Z6827` cannot be equal to `M1180_Z6827` and so for `K5900_Z6828`. `I2510` has only one value so it gets matched.

You can use below query if your requirement is exactly what you have mentioned in your desired output.

```
SQL> WITH tvl_detail AS
      2   (SELECT 'M1180_Z6827' tvl_cd_list FROM dual
      3    UNION ALL
      4    SELECT 'K5900_Z6828' FROM dual
      5    UNION ALL
      6    SELECT 'I2510' FROM dual)
      7   ---------------------------
      8   --- End of data preparation
      9   ---------------------------
     10  SELECT regexp_substr(tvl_cd_list, '[^_]+', 1, LEVEL) AS tvl_cd_list
     11    FROM tvl_detail
     12  CONNECT BY regexp_substr(tvl_cd_list, '[^_]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
     13         AND PRIOR tvl_cd_list = tvl_cd_list
     14         AND PRIOR sys_guid() IS NOT NULL;
```

OUTPUT:

```
TVL_CD_LIST
--------------------------------------------
I2510
K5900
Z6828
M1180
Z6827
```