# Oracle Regexp_ help to do a replace on string

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, regexp-replace

I have a field that has several name values seperated by `$;`, like below:

```
$;James$;Paul$;
```

I have a function available on the names that allows me to identify data from a different table i.e. email address.
However the function only works on a single name value.
So I need to do a substring to get each name value and then run a replace command that runs the function to pull out their email address.
I want to get the following responses James@emailserver.com, Paul@emailserver.com.

So my question is: how can I run a regexp_replace command to identify the names and then split them out to run the replace?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
with
     name_list ( id, str ) as (
       select 1, '$;James$;Paul$;'      from dual union all
       select 2, '$;Jane$;Emily$;Ann$;' from dual
     )
select id, substr(str, instr(str, '$;', 1, level) + 2,
              instr(str, '$;', 1, level+1) - instr(str, '$;', 1, level) - 2) as name
from   name_list
connect by level <= regexp_count(str, '\$;') - 1
       and prior id = id
       and prior sys_guid() is not null
;

ID   NAME
--   -----
 1   James
 1   Paul
 2   Jane
 2   Emily
 2   Ann
```

And then you can use this for your comparisons.

Alternatively, if you need to see if the name `James` is in your input string (and assuming `James` is the value in a column `name_col`):

```
... where name_list.str like '$;' || name_col || '$;'
```

and you don't need to split the string anymore. The concatenations are necessary, though, because you don't want `Anne` in the name list to match the name `Ann` in the column.

Answer (score 0):

This function helps me to split a varchar:

```
function f_split_string( p_string varchar2, p_separator varchar2, p_pos number) return varchar2
is
v_string varchar2(100);
begin
     select partition into v_string from
         (select rownum as n , partition from
             (select regexp_substr(p_string, '[^'||p_separator||']+', 1, level) partition from dual
             connect by regexp_substr(p_string, '[^'||p_separator||']+', 1, level) is not null)
         ) t1
     where t1.n = p_pos;

     return trim(v_string);
exception
    when others then return 'nfound';
end;
```

Example call:

```
/*using the params*/
p_string := '$;James$;Paul$;'; --string to parse
p_separator := '$;'; --separator
p_pos := 1; --position to get
f_split_string(p_string,p_separator,p_pos) /*return 'James'*/

/*if p_pos :=2*/
f_split_string(p_string,p_separator,p_pos) /* return 'Paul' */

/*if p_pos :=3*/
f_split_string(p_string,p_separator,p_pos) /*return 'nfound' */

/*if p_pos :=0*/
f_split_string(p_string,p_separator,p_pos) /* return 'nfound' */
```

Comment: I'm afraid your solution does not handle NULL list elements and if one is encountered will return the wrong data.  Give it `'$;James$;$;Paul$;George'` and ask for the 3rd position. Using the regex `'[^,]+'` (as commonly found) is dangerous. http://stackoverflow.com/a/31464699/2543416