# When I run this query in argos reports I am getting this error of invalid character

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-substr

```
select regexp_substr('SMITH,ALLEN,WARD,JONES','[^,]+', 1, level)
from dual
connect by regexp_substr('SMITH,ALLEN,WARD,JONES', '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null;
```

Comment: The SQL is valid so the problem lies with Argos Reports. You need to take this up with Evisions

Comment: Why not show the error?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include the error, so we don't know which character is invalid.  Here's a different version that does the same thing but handles NULL list elements.  Since it does not contain a circumflex let's see if that's the culprit:

```
select regexp_substr('SMITH,ALLEN,WARD,JONES','(.*?)(,|$)', 1, level, NULL, 1)
from dual
connect by level <= regexp_count('SMITH,ALLEN,WARD,JONES', ',')+1;
```

Please let us know the results.

P.S.  Don't use the regex format `'[^,]+'` to parse lists as it will return incorrect values if there are NULL list elements.  See this post for explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31464699/2543416