# Search comma separated value in oracle 12

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a Table - `Product` In Oracle, wherein `p_spc_cat_id` is stored as comma separated values.

```
p_id p_name p_desc p_spc_cat_id
1    AA     AAAA   26,119,27,15,18
2    BB     BBBB   0,0,27,56,57,4
3    BB     CCCC   26,0,0,15,3,8
4    CC     DDDD   26,0,27,7,14,10
5    CC     EEEE   26,119,0,48,75
```

Now I want to search `p_name` which have `p_spc_cat_id` in `'26,119,7'` And this search value are not fixed it will some time `'7,27,8'`. The search text combination change every time

my query is:

```
select p_id,p_name from product where p_spc_cat_id in('26,119,7');
```

when i execute this query that time i can't find any result

Comment: You should generally avoid storing CSV in your tables like this.  Old habits die hard; better to start good habits now.

Comment: currently this concept is working in my live application so i can't change next time i will avoid this,Please tell me about new concept to storing this type value

Comment: So `'26,119,7'` is a **string**, which means the IN gets interpreted as `=`. So what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: The problem with this approach is it's never a problem for the developer who writes the storage code. They take a string, they store it in a character column, job done. But they have run up a ton of technical debt for the poor souls who have to retrieve the stored values. They have to write some truly nasty code.

Comment: Please don't add tags for sake of getting attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am little late in answering however i hope that i understood the question correctly.

Read further if: you have a table storing records like

```
1. 10,20,30,40
2. 50,40,20,70
3. 80,60,30,40
```

And a search string like '10,60', in which cases it should return rows 1 & 3.

---

Please try below, it worked for my small table & data.

```
create table Temp_Table_Name (some_id number(6), Ab varchar2(100))
insert into Temp_Table_Name values (1,'112,120')
insert into Temp_Table_Name values (2,'7,8,100,26')
```

Firstly lets breakdown the logic:

- The table contains comma separated data in one of the columns[Column AB].
- We have a comma separated string which we need to search individually in that string column. ['26,119,7,18'-X_STRING]
- ID column is primary key in the table.

1.) Lets multiple each record in the table x times where x is the count of comma separated values in the search string [X_STRING]. We can use below query to create the cartesian join sub-query table.

```
Select Rownum Sequencer,'26,119,7,18' X_STRING 
from dual 
CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= (LENGTH( '26,119,7,18') - LENGTH(REPLACE( '26,119,7,18',',',''))) + 1
```

Small note: Calculating count of comma separated values =

```
Length of string - length of string without ',' + 1 [add one for last value]
```

2.) Create a function PARSING_STRING such that PARSING_STRING(string,position). So If i pass:

```
PARSING_STRING('26,119,7,18',3) it should return 7.

CREATE OR REPLACE Function PARSING_STRING
(String_Inside IN Varchar2, Position_No IN Number) 
Return Varchar2 Is
    OurEnd   Number; Beginn Number;
Begin

    If Position_No < 1 Then 
    Return Null; 
    End If;

    OurEnd := Instr(String_Inside, ',', 1, Position_No);

    If OurEnd = 0 Then
        OurEnd := Length(String_Inside) + 1;
    End If;

    If Position_No = 1 Then
        Beginn := 1;
    Else
        Beginn := Instr(String_Inside, ',', 1, Position_No-1) + 1;
    End If;

    Return Substr(String_Inside, Beginn, OurEnd-Beginn);

End;
/
```

3.) Main query, with the join to multiply records.:

```
select t1.*,PARSING_STRING(X_STRING,Sequencer) 
from Temp_Table_Name t1,
(Select Rownum Sequencer,'26,119,7,18' X_STRING from dual 
CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= (Select (LENGTH( '26,119,7,18') - LENGTH(REPLACE( 
'26,119,7,18',',',''))) + 1 from dual))  t2
```

Please note that with each multiplied record we are getting 1 particular position value from the comma separated string.

4.) Finalizing the where condition:

```
Where
/* For when the value is in the middle of the strint [,value,] */
AB like '%,'||PARSING_STRING(X_STRING,Sequencer)||',%'
OR
/* For when the value is in the start of the string [value,] 
parsing the first position comma separated value to match*/
PARSING_STRING(AB,1) = PARSING_STRING(X_STRING,Sequencer)
OR
/* For when the value is in the end of the string [,value] 
parsing the last position comma separated value to match*/
PARSING_STRING(AB,(LENGTH(AB) - LENGTH(REPLACE(AB,',',''))) + 1) = 
PARSING_STRING(X_STRING,Sequencer)
```

5.) Using distinct in the query to get unique ID's

**[Final Query:Combination of all logic stated above: 1 Query to find them all]**

```
select distinct Some_ID
from Temp_Table_Name t1,
(Select Rownum Sequencer,'26,119,7,18' X_STRING from dual 
CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= (Select (LENGTH( '26,119,7,18') - LENGTH(REPLACE( '26,119,7,18',',',''))) + 1 from dual))  t2
Where
AB like '%,'||PARSING_STRING(X_STRING,Sequencer)||',%'
OR
PARSING_STRING(AB,1) = PARSING_STRING(X_STRING,Sequencer)
OR
PARSING_STRING(AB,(LENGTH(AB) - LENGTH(REPLACE(AB,',',''))) + 1) = PARSING_STRING(X_STRING,Sequencer)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like to find it:

```
select p_id,p_name from product where p_spc_cat_id like '%26,119%'
or p_spc_cat_id like '%119,26%' or p_spc_cat_id like '%119,%,26%' or p_spc_cat_id like '%26,%,119%';
```

Comment: This might work for the small dataset in the question, but it is logically wrong because it would return empty set for `119,26`.  Normally we would not care about the order of appearance.

Comment: It will work if there was data available in 26,119,0 sequence  if data is in 26,0,119 format that time it was not  give any result

Comment: Now write a solution which works for `'7,27,8'` as well.

Comment: Search Id combination generate dynamic so order or apperence of it is not fixed

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p_id,p_name
FROM product
WHERE p_spc_cat_id
LIKE '%'||'&i_str'||'%'`
```

where `i_str` is `26,119,7`  or  `7,27,8`

Answer (score 0):

Use the Oracle function instr() to achieve what you want. In your case that would be:

```
SELECT p_name 
FROM product 
WHERE instr(p_spc_cat_id, '26,119') <> 0;
```

[Oracle Doc for INSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_1103.htm#OLADM564)

Answer (score 0):

If the string which you are searching will always have 3 values (i.e. 2 commas present) then you can use below approach.

```
    where  p_spc_cat_id like regexp_substr('your_search_string, '[^,]+', 1, 1) 
or p_spc_cat_id like regexp_substr('your_search_string', '[^,]+', 1, 2) 
or p_spc_cat_id like regexp_substr('your_search_string', '[^,]+', 1, 3)
```

If you cant predict how many values will be there in your search string
(rather how many commas) in that case you may need to generate dynamic query.

Unfortunately sql fiddle is not working currently so could not test this code.

Comment: Don't use the regex `'[^,]+'` for parsing list elements as it will not return what you expect if your list has NULL elements.  See here for more info and a different regex that allows for NULLs : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464275/split-comma-separated-values-to-columns-in-oracle/31464699#31464699

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses CTE's.  "product" builds the main table.  "product_split" turns products into rows so each element in p_spc_cat_id is in it's own row.   Lastly, product_split is searched for each value in the string '26,119,7' which is turned into rows by the connect by.

```
with product(p_id, p_name, p_desc, p_spc_cat_id) as (
  select 1, 'AA', 'AAAA', '26,119,27,15,18' from dual union all
  select 2, 'BB', 'BBBB', '0,0,27,56,57,4'  from dual union all
  select 3, 'BB', 'CCCC', '26,0,0,15,3,8'   from dual union all
  select 4, 'CC', 'DDDD', '26,0,27,7,14,10' from dual union all
  select 5, 'CC', 'EEEE', '26,119,0,48,75'  from dual
),
product_split(p_id, p_name, p_spc_cat_id) as (
  select p_id, p_name, 
         regexp_substr(p_spc_cat_id, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, level, NULL, 1)
  from product
  connect by level <= regexp_count(p_spc_cat_id, ',')+1   
    and prior p_id = p_id
    and prior sys_guid() is not null 
)
-- select * from product_split;
select distinct p_id, p_name
from product_split
where p_spc_cat_id in(
  select regexp_substr('26,119,7', '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, level, NULL, 1) from dual
  connect by level <= regexp_count('26,119,7', ',') + 1
)
order by p_id;

      P_ID P_
---------- --
         1 AA
         3 BB
         4 CC
         5 CC

SQL>
```