# splitting a comma separated field and use in 'IN' clause oracle sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have already viewed similar questions but didn't find the answer I am looking for. My table looks like this.

```
ID  Name  Group
1   R1    A,B
2   R2    C,D,E
3   R3    A
4   R4    B,E
```

What I am looking for is able to use the 'Group' field in an IN clause where the IN clause will be a prompt.
Example: `Group in ('A','B','C')`

I am not a pl/sql expert so would truly appreciate the help!

Note: Changing the table structure is not an option. Previous solutions does not take into consideration passing multiple values which are in the format 'A','B','C' instead of 'A,B,C'

Comment: You can't use the Group "field" in an IN condition, because the IN condition requires a comma-separated list of individual strings (in your example). The table stores a single string - the fact that it contains commas within the string doesn't make it something else (namely, a list of many strings, separated by comma). So, you must either split those strings before using in an IN condition, or you must use a different condition instead of IN. (For example you could use LIKE.) Then: Why is changing the table structure not an option? That should be the first thing to consider.

Comment: Both methods (splitting the string and using a LIKE condition instead of IN) have been shown in many other questions on this site, did you do a search before posting the question?

Comment: change the structure.  it is an option.

Comment: I have already looked through other solutions including the In_List function by ask tom but not getting the results. These tables are populated by our application and the structure cannot be changed. I can use a split function but the values in the Group column is not fixed so not sure how to proceed.

Comment: This post has several solutions for this issue.  Of course I'm partial to my own....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45183349/search-comma-separated-value-in-oracle-12/45246919#45246919