# Convert delimited string to rows in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

I used to use below query to convert comma delimited string to rows -

```
select regexp_substr('A,B,C,D','[^,]+', 1, level) from dual
connect by regexp_substr('A,B,C,D', '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null;
```

But, now my delimiter is - '~^'

I am not able to use same query for this delimiter.

```
select regexp_substr('A~^B~^C~D^E','[^~^]+', 1, level) from dual
    connect by regexp_substr('A~^B~^C~D^E', '[^~^]+', 1, level) is not null;
```

I expect -

Column

```
A
B
C~D^E
```

Please help

OR May be is it possible to get nth element if delimiter provided is ~^

Best Regards

Comment: Post some sample input data please

Comment: A~^B~^C~D^E your input?

Comment: yes...that would be my input

Comment: Why are you doing this in the database?  I could argue that your data was not sufficiently scrubbed to warrant being brought into Oracle.

Comment: This is going to be my input to procedure....In fact actually, it would be multiple SMS delimited by ~^ . Thats why I am using this special delimiter as there is high chance that comma and other characters can be used in SMS body

Comment: I strongly agree with Tim, such scrubbing operations can be done easily in java/python, c etc. Data in the tables need to be stored in a way it is readable. It is not a good design of the application. Better to handle it in the SMPP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Riffing off [this method for splitting a string while allowing for nulls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31464699/266304):

```
select regexp_substr('A~^B~^C~D^E','(.*?)(~\^|$)', 1, level, null, 1) from dual
connect by level < regexp_count('A~^B~^C~D^E','(.*?)(~\^|$)');

REGEXP_SUBS
-----------
A
B
C~D^E
```

As in the linked answer it looks for any characters, non-greedily,  followed by the combination of `~^` (with the caret escaped, so `~\^`) or end-of-line. The `regexp_substr()` calls also [uses the optional arguments](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions164.htm) to specify `subexpr` - so it only gets the first grouping (`.*?`) and not the delimiter itself, which is in the second grouping.

If you want a specific element then that's even closer to the linked post:

```
select regexp_substr('A~^B~^C~D^E','(.*?)(~\^|$)', 1, 3, null, 1) from dual;

REGEX
-----
C~D^E
```

Or as you're doing this in a procedure, use the connect-by query to populate a collection, and then pick out the element you need, if you'll be looking at more than one.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex. One more question- Is it possible to just get particular element. for example say 5th element

Comment: I got it filtering on level column...Thanks Alex

Comment: @AnirudhD - if you only need one then only pick that one out with the regex, extracting them all and then filtering to just get one seems a bit wasteful. But maybe you mean one at a time, in which case a collection might be appropriate; or you might actually want a cursor loop.

Comment: Is it possible to achive in the same query by giving nth element?

Comment: What do you mean? You could do `... from dual where level = 3 connect by ...` but what would be the point?

Comment: sorry my bad!..I dint check your comment for 3rd position. Thanks a lot Alex!

Answer (score 1):

I can't do it with regexp functions - too hard!  How about this bespoke function?

```
create or replace function test (p_str varchar2, p_delim varchar2)
  return SYS.KU$_VCNT -- handy table of VARCHAR2(4000) in SYS
is
  l_str long := p_str;
  l_ret SYS.KU$_VCNT := SYS.KU$_VCNT();
begin
  while instr (l_str, p_delim) > 0 loop
    l_ret.extend;
    l_ret(l_ret.count) := substr(l_str, 1, instr (l_str, p_delim)-1);
    l_str := substr (l_str, instr (l_str, p_delim)+2);
  end loop;
  if l_str is not null then
    l_ret.extend;
    l_ret(l_ret.count) := l_str;
  end if;
  return l_ret;
end;
```

Then:

```
select * from table (test('A~^B~^C~D^E','~^'));

A
B
C~D^E
```

nth element (e.g. 2nd):

```
select column_value from
(select column_value, rownum n from table (test('A~^B~^C~D^E','~^')))
where n = 2;
```

Comment: Thanks Tony...but is there way we could handle this in REGEXP rather than user defined fucntion

Comment: OR May be is it possible to get nth element if delimiter provided is ~^

Comment: Added nth element solution to my answer.  I'm sure it could be done with regexp, but I don't know how.  What's wrong with not using regexp?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . This comes very close:

```
select regexp_substr('A~^B~^C~D^E', '([^~]|[~][^^])+', 1, level) from dual
    connect by regexp_substr('A~^B~^C~D^E', '([^~]|[~][^^])+', 1, level) is not null
```

You can get rid of the `^` by doing:

```
select regexp_replace(regexp_substr('A~^B~^C~D^E', '([^~]|[~][^^])+', 1, level), '^\^', '') from dual
    connect by regexp_substr('A~^B~^C~D^E', '([^~]|[~][^^])+', 1, level) is not null
```

Comment: This would fail for  input 'A~~^B'  . I expect output as first row - A~ and second row B