# regexp_substr strip text between first forward slash and second one

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, regexp-substr

/abc/required_string/2/ should return abc with  regexp_substr

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR ('/abc/blah/blah/', '/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/', 1, 1, NULL, 1) first_val 
from dual;
```

Answer (score 2):

You might try the following:

```
SELECT TRIM('/' FROM REGEXP_SUBSTR(mycolumn, '^\/([^\/]+)'))
  FROM mytable;
```

This regular expression will match the first occurrence of a pattern starting with `/` (I habitually escape `/`s in regular expressions, hence `\/` which won't hurt anything) and including any non-`/` characters that follow. If there are no such characters then it will return `NULL`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can search for `/([^/]+)/`, which says:

- `/` forward slash
- `(` start of subexpression (usually called "group" in other languages)

  - `[^/]` any character other than forward slash
  - `+` match the preceding expression one or more times
- `)` end of subexpression
- `/` forward slash

You can use the 6th argument to [`regexp_substr`](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/regexp_substr.php) to select a subexpression. 
Here we pass `1` to match only the characters between the `/`s:

```
select  regexp_substr(txt, '/([^/]+)/', 1, 1, null, 1)
from    t1
```

[See it working at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fc241/1/0)

Answer (score 1):

Classic `SUBSTR` + `INSTR` offer a simple solution; I know you specified regular expressions, but - consider this too, might work *better* for a large data volume.

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '/abc/required_string/2/' from dual)
  3  select substr(col, 2, instr(col, '/', 1, 2) - 2) result
  4  from test;

RES
---
abc

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to get the 2nd occurrence of a string of characters followed by a forward slash.  It handles the problem if that element happens to be NULL as well.  Always expect the unexpected!

Note:  If you use the regex form of `[^/]+`, and that element is NULL it will return "required string" which is NOT what you expect!  That form does NOT handle NULL elements.  See here for more info: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/31464699/2543416]

```
with tbl(str) as (
  select '/abc/required_string/2/' from dual union all
  select '//required_string1/3/' from dual
)
select  regexp_substr(str, '(.*?)(/)', 1, 2, null, 1)
from    tbl;
```