# How to make substring with the first and third occurrence of a character in oracle11g?

Tags: oracle11g

I have texts like below in a column-

```
a|bbb|cc|dddd
d||ff|gg
a|zzzz|pp|rrr
```

I want to display the text between 1st "|" and 2nd "|" symbols. Below given should be the output.

```
Output
------
bbb
null
zzzz
```

Tried with below query, but it gives me 'ff' instead of null.

```
SELECT regexp_substr('d||ff|gg','[^|]+',1,2) regexp_substr FROM dual;
```

How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31464699/266304) explains why what you are doing doesn't quite work, and how to modify it. You need a slightly more complicated pattern, including escaping the pipe delimiter; and additional arguments to the function call:

```
SELECT regexp_substr('d||ff|gg','(.*?)(\||$)',1,2,null,1) regexp_substr FROM dual;

REGEXP_SUBSTR
--------------------
(null)
```

Or with your other sample rows in a CTE:

```
with t (str) as (
  select 'a|bbb|cc|dddd' from dual
  union all select 'd||ff|gg' from dual
  union all select 'a|zzzz|pp|rrr' from dual
)
select str,
  regexp_substr(str,'(.*?)(\||$)',1,2,null,1) as str2
from t;

STR           STR2
------------- --------------------
a|bbb|cc|dddd bbb
d||ff|gg      (null)
a|zzzz|pp|rrr zzzz
```