# How to get substring index in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, function, oracle11g

I have the following field in my DB (Oracle)

```
Jayson,1990,3,july
```

And i would like to get all the values here.
What would be the solution?

Comment: What have you try? Can you put your code in the question?

Comment: Duplicate of [Split comma separated values to columns in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464275/split-comma-separated-values-to-columns-in-oracle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SELECT CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN 'Name: '
                      WHEN rn =2 THEN 'Year: '
                      WHEN rn = 3 THEN 'Day: '
                      WHEN rn = 4 THEN 'Month: ' END || result "Results"
                      FROM
 (
 WITH TEST (col) AS
 (SELECT 'Jayson,1990,3,july' FROM dual)
 SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) result, ROWNUM rn
FROM TEST
connect BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(col, ',') + 1
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to get all the values here

Where is "here"?

Something like this, perhaps?

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'Jayson,1990,3,july' from dual)
  3  select regexp_substr(col, '[^,]+', 1, level) result
  4  from test
  5  connect by level <= regexp_count(col, ',') + 1;

RESULT
------------------
Jayson
1990
3
july

SQL>
```

**[EDIT, after seeing the comment]**

Two *simple* options: one is to use `REGEXP_SUBSTR`, another one is to use traditional `SUBSTR` + `INSTR` combination:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'Jayson,1990,3,july' from dual)
  3  select
  4    regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, 1) name,
  5    regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, 2) year,
  6    regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, 3) day,
  7    regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, 1) month,
  8    --
  9    substr(col, 1, instr(col, ',', 1, 1) - 1) name_2,
 10    substr(col, instr(col, ',', 1, 1) + 1, instr(col, ',', 1, 2) - instr(col, ',', 1, 1) - 1) year_2,
 11    substr(col, instr(col, ',', 1, 2) + 1, instr(col, ',', 1, 3) - instr(col, ',', 1, 2) - 1) day_2,
 12    substr(col, instr(col, ',', 1, 3) + 1) month_2
 13  from test;

NAME   YEAR D MONTH  NAME_2 YEAR D MONT
------ ---- - ------ ------ ---- - ----
Jayson 1990 3 Jayson Jayson 1990 3 july

SQL>
```

Comment: Sorry for bad description.
I want to get firstly the first name as FirstName , then the date as Date ,then the day as Day 

RESULT:
    Name:
    Jayson

    Date:
     1990

    Day:
    3

Comment: I've modified my message; have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for bad description.
I want to get firstly the first name as FirstName , then the date as Date ,then the day as Day.So i want to return me each time one row.I will execute it 4 times to retrive all results

RESULT:

```
Name:
Jayson

Date:
 1990

Day:
3
```