# How to select multiple columns from dual when I use regexp_substr with connect by clause and level

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

```
SELECT DISTINCT REGEXP_SUBSTR ('id1:id2','[^:]+',1,LEVEL)  R ,
  REGEXP_SUBSTR ('name1:name2','[^:]+',1,LEVEL) D
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR ('id1:id2','[^:]+',1,LEVEL)
  = REGEXP_SUBSTR ('name1:name2','[^:]+',1,LEVEL) 
order by 1;
```

My delimiter is ':' I can only get 1 row (id & name) by using the above query but if I want to get multiple rows with multiple columns ( id & name) how should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your connect-by condition is only going to be true if the ID and name values match - which is not the case for your examples.

You can count the number of elements instead; and in case the counts are different, use `greates()` to pick the higher count:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR ('id1:id2','[^:]+',1,LEVEL) R ,
   REGEXP_SUBSTR ('name1:name2','[^:]+',1,LEVEL) D
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= GREATEST (REGEXP_COUNT ('id1:id2',':'),
  REGEXP_COUNT ('name1:name2',':')) + 1
order by 1;

R       D          
------- -----------
id1     name1      
id2     name2
```

Or a [safer pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464275/split-comma-separated-values-to-columns-in-oracle/31464699#31464699) if you could have empty elements:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR ('id1:id2:id3', '(.*?)(:|$)', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 1) R ,
  REGEXP_SUBSTR ('name1::name3', '(.*?)(:|$)', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 1) D
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= GREATEST (REGEXP_COUNT ('id1:id2:id3',':'),
  REGEXP_COUNT ('name1::name3',':')) + 1
order by 1;

R           D           
----------- ------------
id1         name1       
id2                     
id3         name3
```

Comment: Thanks Alex! you're the best!