# What is the best way to separate and save addresses from a string in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, regex, string, oracle, plsql

In our database we have tables with company addresses. 
Some companies have more than 1 address. In this case we used to save addresses in a column like that:

```
'119021, г Москва, ул Льва Толстого, д 16; 117312, г Москва, ул Вавилова, д 19'
```

So there are a semicolon and space between addresses.

Now I have to create different table where every address has its own row by copying data from existing table.

What instruments should I use in my procedure that

- determine whether there are one or more than 1 addresses in a column
- separate addresses if there are more than 1

Should I use REGEXP? If yes, how?

Comment: It seems possible that `REGEX_SUBSTR()` combined with `CONNECT BY LEVEL` might help you handle this problem. http://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-string-functions/oracle-regexp_substr/

Comment: @o-jones thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I would be remiss if I did not point out for future searchers that storing more than one piece of information in a single column violates first normal form of database design and will give you nothing but trouble down the road.  Since you are remedying this I salute you!

Secondly using the regex pattern of the form `'[^;]+'` to parse delimited strings fails when there are null elements in the list.  See here for more info on why that is a bad idea: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31464699/2543416

Now, I'm not all doom and gloom!  I don't know what characterset you are using but you'll get the idea.  This example uses a regex form that allows for NULL list elements and 1 or more semi-colons followed by a space OR the end of the line.

```
with tbl(id, str) as (
  select 1, '119021-1, г Москва, ул Льва Толстого, д 16; 117312-1, г Москва, ул Вавилова, д 19' from dual union all
  select 2, '119021-2, г Москва, ул Льва Толстого, д 16;;; 117312-2, г Москва, ул Вавилова, д 19' from dual
)
select id, regexp_substr(str, '(.*?)(;+ |$)', 1, level, NULL, 1) addr_fixed
from tbl
connect by regexp_substr(str, '(.*?)(;+ |$)', 1, level, NULL, 1) is not null
  and prior id = id
  and prior sys_guid() is not null;


        ID ADDR_FIXED                                   
---------- ---------------------------------------------
         1 119021-1, ¿ ¿¿¿¿¿¿, ¿¿ ¿¿¿¿ ¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿, ¿ 16   
         1 117312-1, ¿ ¿¿¿¿¿¿, ¿¿ ¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿, ¿ 19        
         2 119021-2, ¿ ¿¿¿¿¿¿, ¿¿ ¿¿¿¿ ¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿, ¿ 16   
         2 117312-2, ¿ ¿¿¿¿¿¿, ¿¿ ¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿, ¿ 19        

4 rows selected.
```

Comment: Thank you! I've tried this and this is what I was looking for!

Comment: I wish one day REGEXP will not be such a mystery to me

Answer (score 0):

> determine whether there are one or more than 1 addresses in a column

You could use [`REGEXP_COUNT`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions135.htm) to count how many times the semi-colon character appears in the field : adding 1 to that to gives you the count of addresses :

```
SELECT t.*, regexp_count(t.address, ';') + 1 FROM mytable t;
```

> separate addresses if there are more than 1

To split the string into new rows, as commented by O.Jones, an approach is to use regex functions in combination with a recursive query, like :

```
SELECT TRIM(regexp_substr( t.address, '[^;]+', 1,  LEVEL )) regexp_substr
FROM mytable t
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count( t.address,  ';' ) + 1;
```

This type of statement can be embedded into an `INSERT ... AS SELECT` or `CREATE ... AS SELECT` order, for example :

```
CREATE TABLE newtable as
SELECT t.name, TRIM(regexp_substr( t.address, '[^;]+', 1,  LEVEL )) regexp_substr
FROM mytable t
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count( t.address,  ';' ) + 1;
```

**[Demo on Oracle 11gR2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e8b489b34ea26d2d6175631aeb31cdfa)**

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed and helpful answer! This works perfectly!

Comment: how to modify `'[^;]+'` so it could match zero, one or more than one semicolon. It turned out that we have in our database the following values:
address1;address2 or address1;; address2? or even address1;;; address2