# how to properly split a tab delimited value into individual columns in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working with this query:

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_SUBSTR ('test1   test2   test3', '[^\t]+', 1, 1) field1,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR ('test1   test2   test3', '[^\t]+', 1, 2) field2,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR ('test1   test2   test3', '[^\t]+', 1, 3) field3
FROM DUAL
```

I'm looking for each field to have each value.  this is a tab-delimited string. But I'm getting random outputs to it.

Looking for:

```
field1    field2    field3
test1     test2     test3
```

Getting:

```
field1    field2    field3
es        es        es
```

what am I missing?

thanks

Comment: By the way and just FYI,  the Posix pattern `'[^[:space:]]+'` works for both  tabs and spaces(even carriage return, newline etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[^\t]+` will match characters that are not a backslash and not a `t` character.

So

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_SUBSTR ('aaatbbb\ccc', '[^\t]+', 1, 1) field1,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR ('aaatbbb\ccc', '[^\t]+', 1, 2) field2,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR ('aaatbbb\ccc', '[^\t]+', 1, 3) field3
FROM DUAL
```

Will output:

```
FIELD1 | FIELD2 | FIELD3
:----- | :----- | :-----
aaa    | bbb    | ccc
```

Having split the string on `\` and `t`

If you want to split it on a tab character then:

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_SUBSTR ('test1' || CHR(9) || 'test2' || CHR(9) || 'test3', '[^' || CHR(9) || ']+', 1, 1) field1,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR ('test1' || CHR(9) || 'test2' || CHR(9) || 'test3', '[^' || CHR(9) || ']+', 1, 2) field2,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR ('test1' || CHR(9) || 'test2' || CHR(9) || 'test3', '[^' || CHR(9) || ']+', 1, 3) field3
FROM DUAL
```

Which outputs:

```
FIELD1 | FIELD2 | FIELD3
:----- | :----- | :-----
test1  | test2  | test3
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2932fa00b4a442a39450382785bd7f4c)*

Answer (score 2):

Characters inside the square brackets are [interpreted as literal characters](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html), not escape characters - so you're matching anything except `'t'` or `'\'` rather than tabs.

You could embed an actual tab character using concatenation:

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_SUBSTR ('test1   test2   test3', '[^'||chr(9)||']+', 1, 1) field1,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR ('test1   test2   test3', '[^'||chr(9)||']+', 1, 2) field2,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR ('test1   test2   test3', '[^'||chr(9)||']+', 1, 3) field3
FROM DUAL;

FIELD FIELD FIELD
----- ----- -----
test1 test2 test3
```

You may have problems with adjacent tabs though:

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_SUBSTR ('test1       test3', '[^'||chr(9)||']+', 1, 1) field1,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR ('test1       test3', '[^'||chr(9)||']+', 1, 2) field2,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR ('test1       test3', '[^'||chr(9)||']+', 1, 3) field3
FROM DUAL;

FIELD FIELD FIELD3
----- ----- ------
test1 test3
```

A [safer pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464275/split-comma-separated-values-to-columns-in-oracle/31464699#31464699) is:

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_SUBSTR ('test1       test3', '(.*?)('||chr(9)||'|$)', 1, 1, null, 1) field1,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR ('test1       test3', '(.*?)('||chr(9)||'|$)', 1, 2, null, 1) field2,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR ('test1       test3', '(.*?)('||chr(9)||'|$)', 1, 3, null, 1) field3
FROM DUAL;

FIELD FIELD2 FIELD
----- ------ -----
test1        test3
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=354022fa88cdcd61dadbe0554fc929e3)

Comment: Sorry Alex.  Great answer but MT0 said it first.  I'll give you a +1 tho.

Comment: I'm used to MTO beating me *8-) I've added a note about adjacent tabs (empty elements, I suppose), which may or may not be relevant to you.

Comment: I +1'd it as well.  Thanks!