# How to get the nth string from the delimited strings using REGEXP_SUBSTR in Oracle

Tags: oracle, regexp-substr

I have a string which is delimited by `#` and I want the third set / cell in the string.

For example:

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR( 'abc#def##########xyz','[^#]+', 1,1,null) from dual;
```

Outputs: abc

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR( 'abc#def##########xyz','[^#]+', 1,2,null) from dual;
```

Outputs: def

However

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR( 'abc#def##########xyz','[^#]+', 1,3,null) from dual;
```

Outputs: xyz

But what I expect is to get `null` since the third cell between `##` is empty.

Answer (score 3):

This is [a familiar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464275/split-comma-separated-values-to-columns-in-oracle/31464699#31464699). Use a different pattern as that answer suggests:

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR( 'abc#def##########xyz','(.*?)(#|$)', 1, 1, null, 1) from dual;

abc

select REGEXP_SUBSTR( 'abc#def##########xyz','(.*?)(#|$)', 1, 2, null, 1) from dual;

def

select REGEXP_SUBSTR( 'abc#def##########xyz','(.*?)(#|$)', 1, 3, null, 1) from dual;

(null)

select REGEXP_SUBSTR( 'abc#def##########xyz','(.*?)(#|$)', 1, 12, null, 1) from dual;

xyz
```

Or get all of them at once with a hierarchical query (or recursive CTE):

```
select level as pos,
  REGEXP_SUBSTR( 'abc#def##########xyz','(.*?)(#|$)', 1, level, null, 1) as result
from dual
connect by level <= regexp_count('abc#def##########xyz', '#') + 1;

       POS RESULT              
---------- --------------------
         1 abc                 
         2 def                 
         3 (null)              
         4 (null)              
         5 (null)              
         6 (null)              
         7 (null)              
         8 (null)              
         9 (null)              
        10 (null)              
        11 (null)              
        12 xyz                 

12 rows selected.
```

Comment: Thank You so much @alex poole

Answer (score 0):

How about `SUBSTR` + `INSTR` combination?

```
SQL> with test (col) as (select 'abc#def##########xyz' from dual)
  2  select substr(col, instr(col, '#', 1, 2) + 1,
  3                     instr(col, '#', 1, 3) - instr(col, '#', 1, 2) - 1
  4               ) third_string,
  5         --
  6         substr(col, instr(col, '#', 1, 1) + 1,
  7                     instr(col, '#', 1, 2) - instr(col, '#', 1, 1) - 1
  8               ) second_string
  9  from test;

THIRD_STRING    SECOND_STRING
--------------- ---------------
                def

SQL>
```

The `second_string` explained (a simpler case, as it actually returns *something*):

- the first `INSTR` line finds the 2nd appearance of the `#` character
- the second `INSTR` line finds the 3rd appearance of the `#` character and subtracts the 2nd appearance (so it creates a substring length)