# Trimming a substring that will be used on different length strings

Tags: sql, oracle, trim

So I have a string like abcdefg#3h#ijkl12mka#123456#L#5

I am trying to get only the string 123456 out of that string. Note: there are string of different length, so I cant use something like substr(21,length(string)). I do not think i can use something like substr(-11,-1). Does anyone have any advice on how to approach this?

Comment: take a look at regular expressions.

Comment: You'll need to explain the logic behind choosing "123456".

Comment: If it's the nth string you're after, use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31464699/7998591) solution

Comment: that 123456 is the string I need returned. there are other cases where it might be abcdefg#3123h#i4kl12#mka#123456#L#5    - just different lengths but i need that 123456 which is always that length towards the end.

Comment: "towards the end" is too generic.  You need to be able to describe how to find the string you need so it will work every time.  "The 3rd pound sign-delimited field from the end" or "the only field containg > 1 digit no matter where it appears on in the string" or "the last all-digit field that is exactly 6 digits long". What should be returned if the string is not found? NULL?  The entire string?

Comment: The 2nd # is the start position and the 3rd # is the end position. Inside should be only numeric characters. If there is not any should return null.

Answer (score 0):

Just take a look here [regex](https://medium.com/factory-mind/regex-tutorial-a-simple-cheatsheet-by-examples-649dc1c3f285).

With this you can define your string which is always there. In your case for example you want to have the string which is surrounded by # and contains only numbers...

- The way to use this in an oracle database is explained [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_re.htm).
- A site where you can test your regex is [here](https://regex101.com/).
- As well as an already answered question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464275/split-comma-separated-values-to-columns-in-oracle/31464699#31464699).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR('abcdefg#3h#ijkl12mka#123456#L#5','[^#]+',1,4) from dual;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f5fb616469b474a40e4902aae5d895de)

Cheers!!