# Split a column data by tokenizing and sending specific tokens into two columns in Oracle

Tags: oracle, split

I have a table data similar to below format in oracle :

```
create table employee_punches (emp_id number(38), name varchar2(40), id number(38), emp_fullname varchar2(80), workdate date, wbt_name varchar2(100), wbt_id number(38), timecodes varchar2(4000));  

insert into employee_punches values (17665, '10048',    1815944,    'Tsirnikas, Adrienne, Marie',   '09-NOV-20',    '381',  10644,  'ON-07:00,OFF-17:30,ON-18:30,OFF-19:12,ON-19:30,OFF-20:00,ON-21:42,OFF-23:00');  
insert into employee_punches values (18630, '30953',    1872069,    'Albert, Katherine, A',         '09-NOV-20',    '1',    10146,  'ON-05:00,OFF-14:30');  
insert into employee_punches values (18960, '37321',    1872482,    'Achimovich, Ashly',            '09-NOV-20',    '725',  10978,  'ON-15:00,OFF-23:00');  
insert into employee_punches values (19081, '39007',    1872713,    'Adams, Patty',                 '09-NOV-20',    '577',  10832,  'ON-07:00,OFF-15:30');  
insert into employee_punches values (19361, '42029',    1873203,    'Albert, Patricia',             '09-NOV-20',    '1',    10146,  'ON-10:00,OFF-22:00');
```

The above table needs to be queried and shown as below table. I need timecodes column be split into IN and and its corresponding OUT punches combination into two different columns as shown below. If there is no corresponding IN or OUT punch we need to leave that as NULL in the output under IN or OUT column accordingly.

Can you please suggest sample Oracle SQL query to convert the above table data into below format? I was trying to use regex_substr function but didn't work properly.

| EMP_ID | NAME | ID | EMP_FULLNAME | WORKDATE | WBT_NAME | WBT_ID | IN | OUT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 17665 | 10048 | 1815944 | Tsirnikas, Adrienne, Marie | 9-Nov-20 | 381 | 10644 | 7:00 | 17:30 |
| 17665 | 10048 | 1815944 | Tsirnikas, Adrienne, Marie | 9-Nov-20 | 381 | 10644 | 18:30 | 19:12 |
| 17665 | 10048 | 1815944 | Tsirnikas, Adrienne, Marie | 9-Nov-20 | 381 | 10644 | 19:30 | 20:00 |
| 17665 | 10048 | 1815944 | Tsirnikas, Adrienne, Marie | 9-Nov-20 | 381 | 10644 | 21:42 | 23:00 |
| 18630 | 30953 | 1872069 | Albert, Katherine, A | 9-Nov-20 | 1 | 10146 | 5:00 | 14:30 |
| 18960 | 37321 | 1872482 | Achimovich, Ashly | 9-Nov-20 | 725 | 10978 | 15:00 | 23:00 |
| 19081 | 39007 | 1872713 | Adams, Patty | 9-Nov-20 | 577 | 10832 | 7:00 | 15:30 |
| 19361 | 42029 | 1873203 | Albert, Patricia | 9-Nov-20 | 1 | 10146 | 10:00 | 22:00 |

Comment: In my question above i am trying to tokenize `timecodes` column by comma and send ON tokens into IN column and immediate next OFF token into OUT column for that IN token.

Comment: look at regular expressions to parse

Comment: Please do not ask [duplicate questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65613117/1509264) just because the first was closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a variant of the common problem "[how do I split a comma-separated list into rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464275/split-comma-separated-values-to-columns-in-oracle)". You might want to review that question for my answer to make sense. **Assuming that your data is clean**, you can do something like this:

```
select emp_id, name, id, emp_fullname, workdate, wbt_name, wbt_id, 
    substr(regexp_substr(timecodes, '[^,]+', 1, level*2-1),4) as punch_in, 
    substr(regexp_substr(timecodes, '[^,]+', 1, level*2),5) as punch_out
from employee_punches
connect by regexp_substr(timecodes, '[^,]+', 1, level*2-1) is not null
      and PRIOR id = id 
      and PRIOR SYS_GUID() is not null  
   order by id, level;
```

You didn't specify what your primary key is, and this solution requires one, so I assumed that `id` will work. If you're using something different, you might need to change that in the `connect by`.

Comment: Perfect solution, thank you very much this is working superb.