# there is a way to transpose two strings and have a table as result?

Tags: oracle19c, oracle-apex-19.1, oracle21c

I have the next two strings:

```
String_Cod   = 14521;65412;65845
String_Flags = 1;0;1


for code 14521 the flag is 1
for code 65412 the flag is 0
for code 65845 the flag is 1
in this order always
```

The result must be something like

[image]

I'm start with this query:

```
select regexp_substr(to_char(:STRING_COD),'[^;]+', 1, level)
from dual
connect BY regexp_substr(to_char(:STRING_COD), '[^;]+', 1, level)
is not null

select regexp_substr(to_char(:STRING_FLAGS),'[^;]+', 1, level)
from dual
connect BY regexp_substr(to_char(:STRING_FLAGS), '[^;]+', 1, level)
is not null
```

But i don't have an idea how continue to join both and get the result i need.

Can somebody give an advise?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the level as another column in each query, and join them together:

```
select c.cod, f.flag
from (
  select level as n, regexp_substr(to_char('14521;65412;65845'),'[^;]+', 1, level) as cod
  from dual
  connect BY regexp_substr(to_char('14521;65412;65845'), '[^;]+', 1, level)
  is not null
) c
join (
  select level as n, regexp_substr(to_char('1;0;1'),'[^;]+', 1, level) as flag
  from dual
  connect BY regexp_substr(to_char('1;0;1'), '[^;]+', 1, level)
  is not null
) f
on f.n = c.n
```

which - with outer joins - would allow for different numbers of elements; or more simply as you suggest they will always match, use the same level for both extracts:

```
select regexp_substr(to_char('14521;65412;65845'),'[^;]+', 1, level) as cod,
  regexp_substr(to_char('1;0;1'),'[^;]+', 1, level) as flag
from dual
connect BY regexp_substr(to_char('14521;65412;65845'), '[^;]+', 1, level)
is not null
```

```
COD   | FLAG
:---- | :---
14521 | 1   
65412 | 0   
65845 | 1
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b89eae5d16b42b1e5bdf381aac87a745)

This method of expanding a list of values also assumes you can never have null elements, in either list. [Read more.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31464699/266304)