# Separating Text by Delimiter using regexp_subtr

Tags: regex, regexp-substr

I am using plsql to separate parts of my text.
The text:
'a^b^c^d^e'

```
declare
test varchar2(10);
begin
select 'a^b^c^d^e' into test from dual;
dbms_output.put_line('1. '|| regexp_substr(test, '[^^]+', 1, 1));
dbms_output.put_line('2. '|| regexp_substr(test, '[^^]+', 1, 2));
dbms_output.put_line('3. '|| regexp_substr(test, '[^^]+', 1, 3));
dbms_output.put_line('4. '|| regexp_substr(test, '[^^]+', 1, 4));
dbms_output.put_line('5. '|| regexp_substr(test, '[^^]+', 1, 5));
end;
```

Output:

```
1. a
2. b
3. c
4. d
5. e
```

This works as expected, until a null is found in the middle (i.e. 'a^b^^d^e').
I expect that output to be:

```
1. a
2. b
3. 
4. d
5. e
```

but the actual output is:

```
1. a
2. b
3. d
4. e
5.
```

I'm not real good at regex but I am most of the way there.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464275/split-comma-separated-values-to-columns-in-oracle/31464699#31464699) for more detail.  Don't use the format `'[^^]+'` for parsing strings!  It returns unexpected results when there is a NULL element in the list and will get you in big trouble as it will return the wrong element.  Instead use this form of `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` as it handles NULL list elements:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR('a^b^^d^e', '(.*?)(\^|$)', 1, 4, NULL, 1)
```

Run it and you'll see you will get 'd' returned as expected.